# mysql how have in a report the ids of the newly inserted, updated, deleted records per month

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I need to have a report on a per month basis, on which records where updated.

```
Column     Type        Comment
id         bigint(20)  NULL 
deleted    bit(1)      NULL  
title      text        NULL  
updateDate datetime    NULL
```

I can get the records updated in any given period, with the help of the updateDate column.

How could I get a new table, that would not interfere with the scheme, that would have also in there stored the following info?

```
id action  updatedate
```

I would like to have a result like

```
id  action    updatedate
23  inserted  2019-12-19 11:28:03
35  updated   2019-12-19 10:43:22
```

Could you please give me an example of how I could achieve the above?

I have created a query that returns to me the records that had an update date between dates, but this does not give me a clue of what was the action that took place. I also do not want to alter at all the current scheme, so I would like to store the actions info in a new table

Answer (score 0):

You could add some more timestamps:

```
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at
```

Or just two columns (`updated_at`) and another field which contain the performed action.

Whenever you perform an action, you have to set the timestamp to the current time.

Why do you want to store the information in another table? Isn't it enough to query the changes and display them without another table?

The query could look like this:

```
SELECT id, action, updated_at from table where MONTH(updated_at) = 4;
```

The query would select and return all of the changes in April.

Comment: i would rather not mess with the current tables, and cannot do anything with code, since this is a stalled old application. I just need to perform all actions with mysql commands, and store all results in a new table